# MUC/Sub Remove user subscription automatically

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I am trying to develop a chat app using Ejabberd 16.09, the only way i find to unsubscribe a user is

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.example'
to='coven@muc.shakespeare.example'
type='set'
id='E6E10350-76CF-40C6-B91B-1EA08C332FC7'>
```

There is any way to automatically unsubscribe the user when he leave the room?

Or anyway to someone else to remove his subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is any way to automatically unsubscribe the user when he leave
>   the room?

No.It can not be done.
The purpose of introducing MUC/Sub is that even if user is not part of room, one can get notification/messages via subscription which won't happen in case of normal muc behavior(xep-0045).

If you want to unsubscribe when user leaves room, then i don't see any reason why you are using MUC/SUB.Normal MUC will properly suit for your behavior.